# Removing tags from nested list

Tags: python

I have a nested list in this form:

```
[[u' (SBAR - TMP (WHADVP-1 (WRB When)) (S (NP-SBJ (PRP it)))']
[u'(NP-SBJ (DT the) (NNS traders))']
[u'(NP (NNS orders) (S (-NONE- *ICH*-2)))']
[u'(PP-MNR (IN via) (NP (NNS computers)))']
[u'(S-2\n  (NP-SBJ (-NONE- *))\n  (VP\n    (TO to)]]
```

I want to remove the tags and this output:

```
((when it)(the traders)(orders)(via computers))
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it in python?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there an indicator of what is a 'tag' vs a 'word' which you want? Any specific _structure_ to the brackets? I would want try to convert those to tuples to extract the specific parts.

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error in your code listing: the last unicode string isn't terminated. (Probably just a missing `'` before the `]]` part.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get everything that isn't uppercase. I don't know what you consider a tag or not so you can start with something along these lines:

```
import re

arr = [[u' (SBAR - TMP (WHADVP-1 (WRB When)) (S (NP-SBJ (PRP it)))'],
    [u'(NP-SBJ (DT the) (NNS traders))'],
    [u'(NP (NNS orders) (S (-NONE- *ICH*-2)))'],
    [u'(PP-MNR (IN via) (NP (NNS computers)))'],
    [u'(S-2\n  (NP-SBJ (-NONE- *))\n  (VP\n    (TO to)']]

res = [' '.join(re.findall(r'(\b[A-Za-z][a-z ]+\b)', s[0])) for s in arr]

print(res)
# [u'When it', u'the traders', u'orders', u'via computers', u'to']
```